# Can't Enter SQL Command with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get my program to make an entry into my SQL Server database but when I run it I get an error saying incorrect syntax near ')'.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AJ-PC;Initial Catalog=Customers;Integrated Security=True");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customers ('1', '1', '1', '1000/01/01', '1', '1')", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior"_

Comment: You'd also be better learning the right way to do it using parameters, see the following answer for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19956944/1599751

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customers(col1, col, col3, ....) VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '1000/01/01', '1', '1')", conn);
                                                                              ******
```

You need to specify the **`VALUES`** keyword, and I would *also* recommend to always specify the explicit list of columns in the table you're inserting into.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `VALUES` keyword in the query

```
INSERT INTO Customers VALUES ('1', '1', '1', '1000/01/01', '1', '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customers (column names...) values('1', '1', '1', '1000/01/01', '1', '1')",con);
```

You are not specifying column names and Values Keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answers the question in a bit different way. But this is for the future reference. I would suggest you to use `try...catch...finally` block.

```
SqlCommand cmd;
try {
    conn.Open();
    string query = "INSERT INTO Customers (col1, col2, col3,...) VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3',...)";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    int RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if(RowsAffected > 0) {
    //If you are on Console:
    Console.WriteLine("1 Row Inserted");

    //If you are on WinForms / WebForms:
    lblMessage.Text = "1 Row Inserted";
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //If you are on Console:
    Console.WriteLine("Some Exception: " + ex.Message.ToString());

    //If you are on WinForms / WebForms:
    lblMessage.Text = "Some Exception: " + ex.Message.ToString();
} finally {
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: or better yet: put your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using (...) { ...... }` blocks!

Answer (score 0):

You mave missed including "VALUES" clause in your command.
You would use it as below

Insert into Table_Name(Col1,Col2,...ColN) VALUES (VAL1,VAL2,...VAL3)

where,
Table_Name- Your Table name
Col1,Col2,...ColN- Column names in your table
VAL1,VAL2,...VAL3- Values supplied to respective columns

Hope this works for you