# How do i fill my datatable automatically with the data in my datagridview?

Tags: c#, sql, selenium, automation

I'm trying to do is an automation, that receives data in a datagridview and after that, my current problem, saving it in sql
I already made some experiments, what I got so far is this,

```
GDataPicker();
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; x++)
            {
                string strquery = @"INSERT INTO table_teste1 VALUES ("

                + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["Rua"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["Código Postal"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["Distrito"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["Concelho"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["Freguesia"].Value + ", "
                + dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells["GPS"].Value + ");";

                cmd.CommandText = strquery;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }
        }
        conn.Close();
```

the problem with this code is that I keep receiving this -> `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'de'.'`

Could anyone try to help me, thanks.

Comment: Parameterize your queries! Not only is it *much* safer, you won't have this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Insert Query Using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956533/sql-insert-query-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Also, what values are you inserting here? It's not clear where the 'de' comes from, so it seems like the data you're trying to insert is interfering with the SQL syntax. (Again, another reason to parameterize, otherwise I hope you're ok with SQL injection)

Comment: No i'm not, but it´s not like i m gonna post this database online, or something of a kind

Comment: Does my code helped you? @PedroAlvim

Answer (score 2):

Try this and do your changes

```
GDataPicker();
conn.Open();

for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; x++)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Rua", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255, "Rua"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Codigo Postal", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255, "Codigo Postal"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Distrito", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255, "Distrito"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Concelho", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255, "Concelho"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Freguesia", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255, "Freguesia"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GPS", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255, "GPS"));

    cmd.Parameters["@Rua"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters["@Codigo Postal"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters["@Distrito"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters["@Concelho"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters["@Freguesia"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters["@GPS"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

    cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery);
    cmd.Connection = con;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Mark it as answered in order to help other people and be guided by it @PedroAlvim

Comment: where you use cmd = new SqlCommand (strquery); says that i can´t assing cmd because  he is variable using

Comment: In that case remove `using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())` @PedroAlvim

Comment: If you need anything else, let me now @PedroAlvim