# Isolated process Azure function error while inserting record to SQL DWH pool

Tags: azure-functions, azure-synapse, azure-functions-isolated

I'm getting below error while trying to upsert a record in Synapse SQL Pool database using isolated process Azure Function.

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
> Functions.GetWeather. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error while
> handling parameter _binder after function returned:.
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Sql: Encountered exception during
> upsert and rollback. (Parse error at line: 2, column: 54: Incorrect
> syntax near 'WITH'.) (111214;An attempt to complete a transaction has
> failed. No corresponding transaction found.). Core Microsoft SqlClient
> Data Provider: Parse error at line: 2, column: 54: Incorrect syntax
> near 'WITH'.

SQL table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE WeatherDataV2 
(
    WeatherDataId BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED NOT ENFORCED, 
    createdDate DATETIME
);
```

Azure function code for isolated process

```
[Function("GetWeather")]
[SqlOutput("dbo.WeatherDataV2", connectionStringSetting: "SqlConnectionString")]
public WeatherData Run([TimerTrigger("%_runEveryHourCron%")] MyInfo myTimer, FunctionContext context)
{
   var weatherDataItem = new WeatherData()
   {
      WeatherDataId = DateTime.Now.Ticks,
      createdDate = DateTime.Now
   };
   return weatherDataItem;
}

public class WeatherData
{
    [Key]
    public long WeatherDataId { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide full sql query and code which you have implemented.

Comment: @RithwikBojja you don't need to write SQL query while using output binding in functions.

Comment: ```Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Parse error at line: 2, column: 54: Incorrect syntax near 'WITH'.``` this staes that there is error near **WITH**? Does your function dodnot have any other class?

Comment: No this is the only method. Somehow it is generating SQL internally using binding configurations:
[SqlOutput("dbo.WeatherDataV2", connectionStringSetting: "SqlConnectionString")]

Answer (score 0):

With the following Code Snippet, it worked successfully and able to insert the data to Synapse SQL Pool Database Table:

1. Created Dedicated SQL Pool Database in the Synapse Studio
2. Created Timer Trigger Function App runs for every 2 minutes with initializing the WeatherDataItem as object with the properties followed `WeatherDataId`, `createdDate` and also as columns in the **WeatherDataV2** Table in SQL.

**Function1.cs**:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Sql;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


namespace Net6IsoFunApp02
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public string SqlConnectionString = "Server=tcp:demosynapse.sql.azuresynapse.net,1433;Initial Catalog=harisynapsesqlpoold;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sqladminuser;Password=<mydbpassword>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        [SqlOutput("dbo.WeatherDataV2", connectionStringSetting: "SqlConnectionString")]
        public WeatherData Run([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] MyInfo myTimer)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");

            var weatherDataItem = new WeatherData()
            {
                WeatherDataId = DateTime.Now.Ticks,
                createdDate = DateTime.Now
            };
            _logger.LogInformation($"WeatherDataId is {weatherDataItem.WeatherDataId} and createdDate is {weatherDataItem.createdDate}");

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
            {
                String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.WeatherDataV2 (WeatherDataId, createdDate) VALUES (@WeatherDataId, @createdDate)";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WeatherDataId", weatherDataItem.WeatherDataId);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@createdDate", weatherDataItem.createdDate);
                  

                    connection.Open();
                    int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    // Check Error
                    if (result < 0)
                        Console.WriteLine("Error inserting data into Database!");
                }
            }
            return weatherDataItem;
        }
    }

    public class WeatherData
    {
        [Key]
        public long WeatherDataId { get; set; }
        public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    }
    public class MyInfo
    {
        public MyScheduleStatus ScheduleStatus { get; set; }
        public bool IsPastDue { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyScheduleStatus
    {
        public DateTime Last { get; set; }
        public DateTime Next { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**.csproj file**:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Sql" Version="1.0.122-preview" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" Version="3.0.36" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

[image]

References: SQL Connection Code taken from [SO Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956533/sql-insert-query-using-c-sharp) provided by @*Andrew Paes*

Comment: thank you @Hari Krishna for taking time to build this, highly appreciated. Unfortunately this is not solving the problem of Function bindings. In your code you are trying to insert the data into database table twice. Once while using 'command.ExecuteNonQuery();' which is running successfully and 2nd time when you use 'return weatherDataItem;' this statement uses the binding definition '[SqlOutput("dbo.WeatherDataV2", connectionStringSetting:....'. You can see result in your database table because of ExecuteNonQuery but output binding is still failing. I hope this make sense to you?

Comment: I'll update you for the 5 Continuous executions

Comment: Function Execution for every 2 minutes as defined in CRON Schedule - https://i.imgur.com/nrgBHUf.png but with upsert error and the database update is successful - https://i.imgur.com/Fw7IxKb.png. I'm checking regarding the error in the console.

Comment: This is exactly the same thing I mentioned in my question.

Comment: When I removed the WITH sub query part from my table creation query - `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WeatherDataV2]
( 
 [WeatherDataId] [bigint]  NOT NULL,
 [createdDate] [datetime]  NULL
)
WITH
(
 DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( [WeatherDataId] ),
 CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
GO` - I have received different type of error. Checking that - will update you. But the data is coming and storing in the synapse sql db pool successfully for the CRON Schedule defined.

Comment: Yes looks like this issue is with Synapse DWH. I manged to run my same code for Azure SQL database :)

Comment: Is it working fine in Azure SQL Database or its the same issue? @KuldeepSingh

Comment: It is working fine with Azure SQL database.